# How to plot Hyperbolic using parametric form with Animation?

Tags: plotting, animation, parametric-functions, hyperbolic

```
Animate[ ParametricPlot[{Cos[\[Theta]], Sin[\[Theta]]}, {\[Theta], 0, a + 0.0001}, PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}], {a, 0, 2 Pi}, AnimationRunning -> False]
```

This gives a nice illutration of the unit circle.

But if I do the same for hyperbolic, then it does not seem to be working.

```
Animate[ ParametricPlot[{Cosh[\[Theta]], Sinh[\[Theta]]}, {\[Theta], 0, a + 0.0001}, PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}}], {a, 0, 2 Pi}, AnimationRunning -> False]
```

I also tried to use **ContourPlot**.

How would I modifiy that so we have a nice animation to show the circle and the hyperbolic functions with the same value of $\theta$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- For hyperbolic curve `x^2-y^2==1` we can set `x=Sec[t]` and `y=Tan[t]`.

```
Animate[ParametricPlot[{Sec[t], Tan[t]}, {t, 0, a}, 
  PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}}, 
  Exclusions -> All], {a, $MachineEpsilon, 2 π}]
```

- `ContourPlot` also work if we extract the points from the figure.

```
Clear[con, pts, lines];
con = ContourPlot[x^2 - y^2 == 1, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}];
pts = Cases[Normal@con, Line[pts_] :> pts, -1];
lines = Map[Line, Partition[#, 2, 1] & /@ pts, {2}] // Flatten;
Animate[Graphics[Take[lines, i], PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}}, 
  Axes -> True], {i, 1, Length@lines, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: Long time no see since ctex.bbs !!!! NICE TRICK!!!!!!

Comment: @CasperYC Since 2018 :-(

Comment: Yes, sadly. I miss it very much!!